# SSL handshake Exception on App browse from other countries

Tags: java, android, ssl

My app is available for many countries. But there are few countries in
which app do not work. it give SSL handshake exception and time out
exception. This happens only for few countries like Saudi Arabia,
 Bahrain, Vatican city etc.

```
W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:406)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:146)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:107)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:161)
```

My Java Api client code

```
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    connection.setRequestMethod(request.getRequestType());

    if (request.getHeaders() != null) {
        Boolean usApkTest = mSharedPreferencesManager.getUsApkTest();
        if (usApkTest) {
            request.getHeaders().put("COUNTRY", "US");
        }
        setConnectionHeaders(connection, request.getHeaders());
    }

    if (request.getBody() != null) {
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        JSONObject body;
        body = new JSONObject(request.getBody());
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(body.toString());
        wr.close();
    } else if (request.getBodyJson() != null) {
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(request.getBodyJson().toString());
        wr.close();
    }

    connection.setReadTimeout(request.getRequestTimeout());
    connection.connect();

    responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    Logger.v("RESPONSE CODE", "RESPONSE CODE: " + responseCode);

    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;

    if (responseCode == 401 || responseCode == 422 || responseCode == 404 || responseCode == 403) {
        if (connection.getErrorStream() != null)
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
    } else
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
    }
```

Do anyone has any idea why this is happening.

I also came across one link 
https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/p0y97/it_sucks_to_be_an_android_user_in_saudi_arabia/
Does this relate anyway for my problem ?